# The most compact map file format?

Tags: android, maps, gis, openstreetmap

I am trying to understand all this map formats for OpenStreetMap and I really got confused.
The OSM wiki has lots of information, but it looks like it is spread all over different places and i cannot get solid understanding of all the formats.

I am looking for something that can be used in Android for offline use. I know that there are lots of frameworks or even done apps that use different file formats, but as for me they file formats they use are all huge.

As I understand the most lightweight format supported by OSM is PBF-Binary, and it is raster format, right?

I have found that it's possible to convert it to *.map format that is vector, right?

The size then is about 40% less than PBF-Binary, but it has to be rendered and it will not be as fast as raster, right?

So another question is, what is the most compact OSM map format that can be used for android?

I know one app that i use a lot - MapsWithMe and it has small map files and they are very fast, but i don't know if it uses raster or vector, i know only they use OSM maps, but as i understand they have created their own format based on it or smth like that.

I have come across GeoJson and the map files are very small, not more than several megabytes. So now i'm getting confused why it is so, why then it's not used for mobile development, cause i googled 'geojson android' and no information about it.

Are there any comparison tables of these formats?

So if somebody has a link where i can learn about all this things, could you please give it to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PBF](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) format is a much smaller alternative to [XML](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). It contains the same raw vector data. You can convert from one format into the other without loosing any information. PBF is smaller and faster because it is binary data whereas XML is plaintext. The OSM wiki has a short overview of [common OSM file formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats).

I don't know where you got the information that GeoJson is small. The size of a map depends on several attributes. Mainly coverage and detail. Usually you don't want to have an offline map covering the whole world on your device because it will be very large. Most of the time you just need a small area, like a country. And often you don't need every information OSM can offer. Roads, cities and important POIs are usually sufficient for routing and searching.

You didn't tell us what you want to do with the map. Just drawing it? Or do you also need a routing and search functionality? What map format would be the most useful for you depends on your use case.

There is already lots of [software for Android using OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android), including various open source programs. You can take a look at them if you need inspiration for your software.

Comment: Thanks, but the only thing i didn't know is that PBF is just compressed XML. I know that you can filter OSM data with osmfilter and osmconvert for converting and i was doing it today, but i wanted to know the best format that is the smallest one? Is there any? Which represents same planet.osm but has the least size? 
Like MapWithMe, they have same planet.osm - 7GB without filtering the data. As for me, i think i will just take the Mapforge and drop some data from the *.map, but with this question i just wanted to know are there any alternatives?

Comment: PBF has no relation to the XML format other than being a lossless encoding of the OSM data. It is the smallest representation of the OSM data and would be hard to beat as the overhead is very small.

Comment: I strongly doubt that MapsWithMe has the whole planet at 7GB without losing *any* information. PBF is the smallest format because it is binary. And the current [Planet](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) has 21GB in PBF. You can't reduce that to 7GB while still containing the same information. But maybe you don't need all the information, that's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: actually as i said before, mapforge binary map file format is 40% smaller than PBF! The OSM site says that "Off-line OSM world countries maps. Whole planet data takes less than 7GB" from here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android 
and "Full map details, nothing is excluded" here 
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapsWithMe
So I mean that it's the most compact that OSM supports but i believe that it's possible to reduce it.

Comment: I can only assume that this information is wrong. Does their map  still include trash cans, street lamps, fire hydrants, the information whether a road has gravel, dirt, sand, grass, concrete or asphalt surface, benches, wayside crosses, bus/cycle/hiking routes, windsocks, power lines, bollards? I doubt it. OSM has [a lot of different map features](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) (and this list just contains the most commonly used ones). MapsWithMe can definitely not include them all for the whole world in 7GB. They will only have reduced information but you won't notice it.